# Integral of difference is less than $\varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose $f\in \mathscr{R}[a,b]$ which means Riemann-integrable on $[a,b]$, then given $\varepsilon>0$ there is a continuously differentiable function $g$ such that $$\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)-g(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x<\varepsilon$$
How does one go on proving it? I tried to relate it with the fact that if I replace continuously differentiable by step function, then we can easily find such a function. So this should be just a notch above. But, I still can't get a hang of it. Can someone give me some hints? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Find

(1) a step function $f_1$,

(2) a piece wise linear function $f_2$ and

(3) a continuously differentiable function $g$ so that

$$\int_a^b |f(x) - f_1(x)| dx ,\  \int_a^b |f_1(x) - f_2(x)| dx , \int_a^b |f_2(x) - g_(x)| dx < \epsilon /3,$$

and then use

$$|f(x) - g(x)| \leq |f(x) - f_1(x)| + |f_1(x) - f_2(x)| + |f_2(x) - g_(x)|.  $$